# Dynamically populate Jqgrid drop-down filter

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I have modified an existing Javascript function to allow me to populate multiple Jqgrid drop-down filters. The code is:

```
 jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: 'http://localhost:58404/JQGridHandler.ashx',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Property ID', 'Property Ref', 'Short Address', 'Scheme Code', 'Scheme Name'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'PropertyID', index: 'PropertyID', width: 70, align: "left", stype: 'text', sortable: true},
                    { name: 'PropertyRef', index: 'PropertyRef', width: 75, align: "left", stype: 'text', sortable: true},
                    { name: 'ShortAddress', index: 'ShortAddress', width: 200,  align: "center", sortable: true},
                    { name: 'SchemeCode', index: 'SchemeCode', width: 80, align: "center", sortable: true },
                    { name: 'SchemeName', index: 'SchemeName', width: 80, align: "center",  sortable: true },
                    {name: 'PropertyType',width: 80},

        ],

        beforeProcessing: function (data) {

            getDropDownValues(data, "PropertyType")

        }

.jqGrid('destroyFilterToolbar')
                .jqGrid('filterToolbar', {
                    stringResult: true,
                    searchOnEnter: false,
                    defaultSearch: "cn"
                });
        } 

function getDropDownValues(data, columnName) {
        var propertyMap = {}, propertyValues = ":All", rows = data, i, symbol;
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            symbol = rows[i].columnName;
            if (!propertyMap.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
                propertyMap[symbol] = 1;
                propertyValues += ";" + symbol + ":" + symbol;
            }
        }
        $(this).jqGrid("setColProp", 'columnName', {
            stype: "select",
            searchoptions: {
                value: propertyValues
            }
        })
    }
```

However, the column name supplied ("PropertyType") is not found in the Json data even though it exists. The original function has the column name explicitly mentioned and works:

```
symbol = rows[i].PropertyType;
```

Does anybody know how I should be referencing a column name which is supplied as a variable as opposed to being explicitly mentioned?

Sample Data:

```
 [{"PropertyID":1,"PropertyRef":"1","ShortAddress":"99 ROCK LANE,BODMIN,PL91 1NR","SchemeCode":"700000","SchemeName":"LODMIN","PropertyType":"HOU"}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your full jqGrid setup and some demo data from the response in order to get help

Comment: I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you pass the string parameter as property in the object will not work.

In runtime this is equivalent to:

symbol = rows[i]."PropertyType"

which is not correct.

Fortunately you can pass it as it is array element. Like this

symbol = rows[i][columnName];

which in runtime will produce

symbol = rows[i]["PropertyType"];

which is correct

Comment: Thank-you Tony. That works! Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Sanxion Not a problem. Glad to help you. Just to note that it is a good practice to accept the answer, so that other reading this can see that it solves the problem